# My Amazon EMR cluster fails to launch. How to resolve Python dependancies?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

My Amazon EMR cluster fails to launch.

```
Terminated with errors
Bootstrap failure
```

I have S3 bucket with this content

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pip install -U \
    matplotlib \
    pandas
```

I try to bootstrap from this S3,something is wrong with Python dependancies.
Logs show:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

My terminal prom shows

```
pip --version       
zsh: command not found: pip

pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I have multiple Python version installed on my Mac OS(used many venvs).
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: maybe its `pip3`?

Comment: @Marcin I must change the boot script script now.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? You can't use `pip3`?

Comment: Works fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I could provide answer for future reference?

Comment: Of course, will accept it.

Comment: Also you can use `python3 -m pip install <lib>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The **solution** was to use `pip3` instead of `pip`. The change also required to update boot scripts.